# How can I perform Collision Detection on rotated rectangles?

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, collision-detection

Okay, I'm trying to write a program that could tell me if any points in a 30x100 rectangle rotated to 140 degrees are inside another 30x100 rectangle rotated to 200 degrees.

Honestly, I don't even know where to start. I thought about re-rotating them before doing normal calculations, but than they still wouldn't match up.

How can I do this?

Comment: So you're basically looking for the intersection between two non-axis-aligned rectangles?  (Or, if they collide at all?)

Comment: Google provides [2D rotated rectangle collision on GameDev.net](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/2d-rotated-rectangle-collision-r2604).

Comment: @Daniel L, I would assume the Z axis, as the questioner is probably talking about 2D rectangles in 2D space.

Comment: @Daniel: It's not only a parallelogram, it's **still a rectangle** - rotating it will never change that.  It doesn't matter if you're rotating about the center, or a corner, or some other point in 2D-space.