# Arbitrary cubes intersection

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, triggers, intersection

i'm trying to do something like trigger in unity, with only cubes(not axis-aligned).
So, I wanna algorithm, where I can get a Boolean with "intersected or not" :

```
public bool intersect(Vector3[] cube1,Vector3 cube2){ 
 if(not)
  return false;
 return true;
}
```

Thanks for your questions!

Comment: See maybe [Non axis aligned bounding box collision and physics](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/20809/non-axis-aligned-bounding-box-collision-and-physics) or [How can I perform Collision Detection on rotated rectangles?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641219/how-can-i-perform-collision-detection-on-rotated-rectangles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look up something called the seperating axis theorem

You end up with 15 axis tests (basically a dot product) between your 2 cubes.

[Here's a little article on it.](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/131598/advanced_collision_detection_.php?page=3)

[Or a bigger pdf paper](http://jkh.me/files/tutorials/Separating%20Axis%20Theorem%20for%20Oriented%20Bounding%20Boxes.pdf)

I can't see any source with a quick search, but I bet it's out there. It's a very common test.